# Applying a CSS style to an ID element when the beginning of its name stays identical and the end varies

Tags: css, wordpress, html, css-selectors

In WordPress, the title of a blog post will usually be formatted using an ID element composed of a prefix such as 'post', that never varies, followed by variable numerical suffix generated by WordPress, corresponding to the sequential post number that is unique for each post.

In the WordPress theme single.php file, using html 5 (but the issue is the same with HTML 4), the code for the blog post title would look as follows:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="main">
```

This generates the following html, say:

```
<article id="post-5434">
```

I'm having difficulties applying a style to the ID, because unless I'm mistaken there doesn't seem to be a way of applying a style to an element when part of its name varies.  In this instance, what I need to do is to style the ID as follows:

```
#post-[sequential number] {
    position: relative;
}

#post-[sequential number] blockquote,#post-[sequential number] ul,#post-[sequential number] ol {
    color: #555;
    margin: 0 14px 5px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

#post-[sequential number] ul li,.entry ul li {
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin: 0 20px 5px;
}

#post-[sequential number] ol li {
    list-style: decimal;
    margin: 0 20px 5px;
}

#post-[sequential number] blockquote {
    font-style: italic;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-left: 21px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

in order to apply the styles listed above to descendants of the #post-[sequential number] ID.

In this instance, adding a class (say, `<article id="post-[sequential number]" class="blog-post">` to the ID wouldn't work, since `position:relative` has to be applied to a block element.

Of course, this result could be easily achieved by adding an extra block element (say, `<div class="blog-post">`) in between #post-[sequential number] and its descendants, and applying the desired styles to it.  But the whole point of using html 5 is to remove unnecessary div elements to make for more semantic markup, so I'd like to find a solution that works without this.

I've saved a working copy of the plain index.html and style.css files (without the WordPress markup) in my sandbox that reflect the above description (i.e., with the ID '#post-5434' in the html and #post (with 'position:absolute') in the css): they can be accessed [here](http://sandbox.donaldjenkins.net/stack-overflow_2011-02-25/index.html).  As you can see, obviously, the desired styles aren't applied to the descendant blockquote and ul elements.

**UPDATE**
There are three possible solutions, all equally valid and appropriate in certain circumstances.  See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Sotiris’ answer is the way to go in CSS. However, if you can edit your WordPress theme, you could add `class="post"` to the HTML, e.g

```
<article class="post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" role="main">
```

To produce this HTML:

```
<article class="post" id="post-5434">
```

Then use the class in your CSS:

```
.post {
    position: relative;
}

/* and so on... */
```

This CSS has the advantage of working in IE 6.

**Edit:**

> In this instance, adding a class (say, `<article id="post-[sequential number]" class="blog-post">` to the ID) wouldn't work, since `position:relative` has to be applied to a block element.

`<article>` is a block-level element. If it’s not showing up as such in your browser, pop this into your CSS file:

```
article {
    display: block;
}
```

[HTML5-aware reset stylesheets like Eric Meyer’s](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/26/reset-v2-0/) do this.

Answer (score 4):

you can select the posts using `div[id*='post-'] { ... }` or even better `div[id^='post-'] { ... }`

The first will select all div elements with id which contains the value in quotes. The second will select all div elements with id which start with the value in quotes.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lx8tW/2/

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  I was guessing some sort of wildcard might work, but I couldn't find one for this issue when I googled it.  Do you mean applying the wildcard to the html?  Because `<article id*="post-5434">` instead of `<article id="post-5434">` still doesn't work.  Or do you mean applying the wildcard to the css? `#post-*` and `#*post` don't work either.

Comment: @Donald you use it in your css. There is no need to change anything in the html. Check the updated answer with example.

Comment: I updated the jsFiddle example to http://jsfiddle.net/Lx8tW/3/. This is just to show how it works with `article` tags, in case there was confusion.

Comment: @Sotiris, @anothershrubery, I've tried applying your suggestions to my issue here, but still not getting it right apparently: [http://jsfiddle.net/astorg/9zYeH/](http://jsfiddle.net/astorg/9zYeH/)

Comment: @Donald there is no reason to edit your html and add the asterisk. This has its role in css. Check it: http://jsfiddle.net/utw8y/1/

Comment: @Donald as Sotiris says, do not change the html at all. I removed the asterisk in your example and produced this. http://jsfiddle.net/9zYeH/3/

Comment: @anothershrubery @Sotiris: Got it to work with your solution also, by reverting the html to the original version, see it in action here: [http://jsfiddle.net/astorg/9zYeH/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/astorg/9zYeH/4/). Really useful, this means both solutions work.

Comment: @anothershrubery @Sotiris: Sorry to come back with another question. Would either of you be able to supply a link to an online resource detailing the method you mentioned?  I'm thinking I could use it to shorten some other css declarations, such as those involving <h1> to <h6> tags… but for that I'd need to use a wildcard that only targeted numbers, as opposed to letters, in the selector name, in to simplify, for instance, the following: `#sidebar * h1, #sidebar * h2, #sidebar * h3, #sidebar * h4, #sidebar * h5, #sidebar * h6{color: #000;font-size: 12px;font-weight: bold;}`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just adding the class of post to article you should really be using:

```
<?php post_class(); ?>
```

That will give you the class of post along with a number of other ones for targeting sticky posts, custom post types, attachments, custom pages...

Comment: Thanks, an excellent suggestion.  I actually have a really simple set up with no need for special styling for different post categories.  But actually your solution can be combined with the CSS to provide a combination of standardization for some styling and finer customization for others.  Basically, all three answers are equally appropriate in certain circumstances.

Comment: the 'recommended' way for wordpress is to use the post_class as some plugins will hook classes contained to style their elements in your post. They may not be hooking .post so they may not quite work on your site.