# Apply CSS Style to New Div IDs

Tags: css, css-selectors

In my wordpress site, the numbers of my div ids for "chimp-button-*" keep changing automatically. Rather than needing to add a new div id each time it changes, is there a way to use a wildcard to capture all div ids starting with chimp-button?

Here's what I have:

```
#chimp-button-7, #chimp-button-6, #chimp-button-5, etc... {
position:relative !important;
}
```

I'm wanting to do something like this...

```
#chimp-button-* {
position:relative !important;
}
```

Sorry, I'm a CSS noob.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179045/applying-a-css-style-to-an-id-element-when-the-beginning-of-its-name-stays-ident

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select these elements with an [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#matching-attrs), so `[id^="chimp-button-"]` would work, however it would also be a poor approach to managing styles.

Instead of trying to select elements based on the an ID pattern, give all these elements a common class attribute, such as `class="chimp-button"`, you can then select all the elements with `.chimp-button`.

Comment: this is the real answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks zzzzBov! I'll try creating a new class first.

Answer (score 1):

This is called to **attribute-selectors**

**Used to this**

```
[id^="chimp-button-"],
[id*="chimp-button-"]{
   // here your  style 
}
```

**[More info attribute-selectors/](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)**

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called attribute selector. An example, using your html structure, is the following: `div[class*='chimp-button-'] {color:red }`

In the place of div you can add any element, and in the place of class you can add any attribute of the specified element.

[***See demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/ucdX4/)

See [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector) and [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors) for more information on CSS attribute selectors.